# Player slips off platform after jumping on its edge

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My player is jumping by:

```
public void Jump() {
   jump++;
   Rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.up * 4.7f;
}
```

If player is on very edge of platform, then after jump he will slip off that platform.

Platform and player have box colliders so there's no round edges. Also colliders have 2dmaterial with 0 friction and 0 bounciness.

Player's rigidbody2d:

[image]

Comment: Set collision detection to `Continuous`. That should do the trick. Rule of thumb is player always have `Continuous` collision detection.

Comment: It's probably about your physics settings.  Under normal conditions, if you want to jump over a floor in a balanced way without slipping, there must be FRICTION between your feet and the ground that will allow you to perform the movement without losing your balance, otherwise you will slide and fall. Can you add a video?

Comment: I've set collision detection to Continuous and set friction of collider material to 0.01 so now it's looks like it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Continuous collision detection (CCD) ensures that fast-moving bodies collide with objects instead of passing, or tunnelling, through those objects.

I'll give you a link to the description [Continuous collision detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ContinuousCollisionDetection.html)